# Handling state in asynchronous Node classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm relatively new to Node and one thing that's concerning me is how I design classes that have to maintain state when I can't be sure they won't be called again before they've finished processing the first call.

e.g.

```
var thing = new Thing();

// Doesn't maintain a state, call it as much as you like
thing.doSomething(function() { alert('done') });
thing.doSomething(function() { alert('done') });
thing.doSomething(function() { alert('done') });

// Maintains some sort of internal state
thing.doSomethingStateful(function() { alert('done') });

// Calling it again messes up the first call if the callback
// hasn't been hit yet because it's still waiting on an I/O 
// operation to complete. 
thing.doSomethingStateful(function() { alert('done') });
```

Is there a design pattern that helps solve this issue? Should I always strive to make Node classes stateless and use an internal state object to track the state of each call? Or is there a convention to differentiate classes that can be used in an asynchronous way and those that maintain a state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the node.js asynchronous model.

Basically, there is a **single** thread of execution which pops callbacks from an event queue. However, the next function queued won't be called until the current one has finished and returned.

It's called asynchronous because the system doesn't block on I/O. Instead, you register a listener and wait until the system notifies you. The system will process other events until the I/O operation finishes so it will keep itself busy.

**edit.**
I hadn't understood your question. I hope this edit addresses it.

It really depends on what you are doing. If you want to allow multiple simultaneous executions of `doSomethingStateful` then using an internal state object is definitely the way to go.

Otherwise if for some reason you can only handle one call at a time, take a look at something like [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) for a function queue implementation.

Comment: I should of been clearer that in this case "thing", or one of it's dependencies, does I/O. Which mean's that the second call to "doSomethingStateful" could be called while still waiting on that I/O?

Comment: Ah, it seems I'm the one misunderstanding. I'll update the answer and elaborate on that :)

Comment: My fault for not being clearer in the question :) (updated it now)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain state you can use internal state as MBlanc suggested but keep in mind that this will work only as long as have one instance of your app running.

Once an app grows you usually spin multiple instances of it (e.g. one per each core in your machine via cluster) or have multiple servers processing requests, at which point internal state might not be the right solution. At that point you'll need to keep state outside of the app via some sort of database (either in-memory or on disk)